# 2 asp:updatepanel and 2 asp:updateprogress controls

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I'm using two asp:updatepanel and 2 asp:updateprogress for them. Update progress shows correctly when I never use AssociatedUpdatePanelID with them, but if I use AssociatedUpdatePanelID the Progress bar never shows.

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upMainPracticeCountry" runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading..." /></ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMainPracticeCountry" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMainPracticeCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMainPracticeState" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the other update panel is

```
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="up2" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upPostalCountry">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading..." /></ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPostalCountry" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPostalCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostalState" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/UpdateProgress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's going in but can you try setting AutoPostback="true" for the dropdown lists in the update panels?